# Adding worklight adapter programmatically

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-studio, worklight-cli

I am creating application which should be **plugin upgradable.**
Problem is that every **plugin** should consist of some **client code** and there should also be some sort of **adapter** which will fetch data to application from 3rd party site/api/... So my **problem** is how do I **add new adapter to server programmatically when someone deploy new plugin??** Is it possible? Or is there better architectonic approach?

Comment: Yetti, if my answer below helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Worklight Studio (plug-in for Eclipse), you cannot programmatically add adapters.

If you are using Worklight 6.2, you can explore the newly released Worklight CLI, which is a command line interface to create projects, applications, adapters, environments, etc... perhaps you could devise a way to intergrate this into a build a system of your own that will fit your needs.

- Training module: [Using CLI to create, build, and manage Worklight project artifacts](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/05_11_Using_CLI_to_create_build_and_manage_Worklight_project_artifacts.pdf)
- User documentation: [Command Line Interface for IBM Worklight Developers](http://engtest01w.francelab.fr.ibm.com:9090/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_wl_cli_features.html)